# Windows 10 shows weird Apps in Alt+Tab Menu

Tags: windows-10, alt-tab

when i use Alt-Tab in Windows 10 Pro, i do not only see the active Windows, but also a bunch of other "Apps", like "Window", "Microsoft Text Input" and "Start". The Screenshot shows my Alt-Tab Menu while i only had Chrome opened, nothing else.

[image: win10 alt tab menu]

I can't tab to these Applications, but still, they are listed in the Alt-Tab Menu.

Anybody knows why this behaviour is there and how i could fix it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**

OK i figured it out, i use a program called "Display Fusion" to manage my 4 screens. This app seems to be coming with a feature that helps you control on which screen and in what style the alt tab menu is popping up - it seems like this was the source of my problem.

Comment: This was fixed for a while, but in the current DisplayFusion release (9.7.1) it's necessary to use the advanced setting "Hide Windows Metro Apps from Alt+Tab". https://www.displayfusion.com/Discussions/View/microsoft-text-input-is-back-on-alt-tab-v971/?ID=4a516c88-1f2a-46ca-9b24-218d3ec63d84#3